# Windows - Write data in stdin for scanf in current process

Tags: winapi, stdin, msvcrt, crt

I'm creating a GTest project which needs to simulate input into scanf of the current process.

I used GetStdHandle() in order to get handle to stdin of current process, but WriteFile seems to fail due to "Invalid Handle" (6).

How then can I put data in stdin for scanf to read?

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio in case it matters.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think it will let you write an input handle

Comment: If standard input is a console, WriteConsoleInput.  Otherwise, your best bet is to create a named pipe and change the standard input to point at it.